# Cancel ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT

Tags: android, android-intent

How do you cancel selecting a file with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT? Going back closes the entire app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("application/*");

startActivityForResult(intent, IMPORT_DATABASE);
```

Comment: No, it does not close the whole app. It just recreates your activity. What goes wrong there? Try to find the exception in the logcat.

Comment: onAvtivityResult is triggered at cancel too.

Comment: Well I feel stupid.... Checking resultcode on onActivityResult is 0 so just return. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (resultCode == 0){
    return;
}
```

Comment: Dont use a '0' but  if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) return;